# Does this software exist: Work enabler/distraction disabler

Tags: windows, macos, mac

Does this idea for Windows and OS X exist.
It's a piece of software that will let the user disable all distraction programs/browser searches that aren't related to the work you're trying to do.
You can customize and set a timer for how long you want to work.
It will be easily customizeable and fast to setup.

Does this software exist?
Can this be done?

I do know about "parental controls", which aren't easy to use, and works very poor in what I have in mind. It needs to be simple and effective.

Please don't refer to using "guest/limited accounts" as this is the same thing.

EDIT
- The app "Selfcontrol" is a part of thing i'm thinking of but not the full package which also will feature block from work unrelated applications.

Comment: How would the software know which programs/searched are "distracting" and which are not? Would you be defining application/website/keyword rules for it yourselft?

Comment: For OS X, there's [SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com) which allows temporarily blocking some domains.

Comment: Cray - yes that is the primary idea, but there might be something else i'm gonna try. Lauri - Thanks for your share, i'll use it as inspiration.

Comment: Also - The software is aimed at schools and workplaces so you can easier follow the lectures without getting distracted, or get your work done on the computer because you won't be able to do anything else on the computer for that period of time.
This requires the application to have some sort of "superuser" rights over the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Many OS X apps support full-screen mode, which some people find a useful way to block out distractions. Combined with the Pomodoro Technique (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique), for which there are dozens of timer apps, and perhaps one of the many browser extensions that block access to certain domains, you can increase your focus quite a bit.